# A free font replacement for Bliss

Tags: font-recommendation, free

I'm looking for a free (meaning 'unrestricted', not just 'costs nothing') font that's as close to [Bliss](http://typography.net/fontfamilies/view/27) as possible. By this, I mean that the license is as permissive as possible - something like [any of these](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#Fonts). Can anyone suggest anything?

[image]

Comment: Is [Open Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans) close enough, and with the desired lack of restrictions?

Comment: @Jongware looks good, and Open Sans is as unrestricted as a font gets, I'd put that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I found it: [Cabin](http://www.dafont.com/cabin.font?text=kindle+fire). It's dual-licenced under the GPL and OFL, and looks pretty much exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

[Open Sans](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans) is a modern, humanist sans font in a wide variety of weights, from Light to Extra Bold, and with a satisfactory large set of glyphs, including Greek, Cyrilic, and lowercase (medieval) digits.

> [image: sample text in Open Sans]
>   <sup>Image courtesy of FontSquirrel</sup>

It comes under the [Apache 2.0 license](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/license/open-sans), which allows modification and redistributing (do read the license for specifics).

The bowls of the lowercase characters are different from Bliss -- they are 'standard', sticking out, rather than rounded. The lowercase `l` is straight, as in many sans fonts, rather than subtly curving.

Answer (score 0):

There's **[Bariol](http://www.bariol.com/)** but it might be a bit too rounded
You can also try **[Ghandi Sans](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/gandhi-sans)**
and also **[Rambla](https://www.behance.net/gallery/Rambla-Alt-(FREE-Typeface)/14436031)**